What are the steps to compile my own ipmid in openbmc?
I cloned the phosphor-host-ipmid repo and added some functionality to it.
The whole repo is in my file system. The path is /home//phosphor-host-ipmid.
I want to run my version of ipmid in qemu with openbmc with romulus image.
I modified the /meta-phosphor/recipes-phosphor/ipmi/phosphor-ipmi-host.inc file. specifically I modified the SRC_URI, LIC_FILES_CHKSUM and HOMEPAGE to point to my local folder.
But when I run bitbake obmc-phosphor-image, I get the following errors
ERROR: phosphor-ipmi-fru-read-inventory-example-native-1.0+git-r1 do_install: ExecutionError('/home/rk/openbmc/build/romulus/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/phosphor-ipmi-fru-read-inventory-example-native/1.0+git/temp/run.do_install.415281', 1, None, None)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/rk/openbmc/build/romulus/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/phosphor-ipmi-fru-read-inventory-example-native/1.0+git/temp/log.do_install.415281
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
| install: cannot stat 'scripts/fru-read-example.yaml': No such file or directory
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/rk/openbmc/meta-phosphor/recipes-phosphor/ipmi/phosphor-ipmi-fru-read-inventory-example-native_git.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '1'
Is the phosphor-ipmi-host.inc the right file to modify?. Or is there some other file?
Thanks
RK
I normally can build romulus image and run it in qemu just fine without my changes.
I really need to build my own ipmid.
Thanks,
RK

better option would be generate patches and apply.

clone phosphor-host-ipmid repository separately
checkout to the commit-id mentioned in recipes-phosphor/ipmi/phosphor-ipmi-host.inc [SRCREV]
make your changes on top of it, generate patches for them.
Apply using SRC_URI += "file://file.patch"

